# Visual Studio 2017 & 2019 highlight occurrences of selected word in scrollbar

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, highlight, visual-studio-2019

When I mark a word (of any kind) I would like all occurrences (in that particular file) of that word to be highlighted in the scrollbar on the right hand side.

This was a feature in VS2015 and VS2013. I cannot imagine that they removed it, I just don't know how to switch it on. None of the apparent possibilities in Tools -> Options (image) helps me.
[image]

Ps. I am using Visual Studio 17 Professional.
Thank you.

Comment: This is now a new feature in Visual Studio 2022 17.4 (on by default), but it highlights both text in the editor and annotates the scrollbar.

It can be toggled on or off using `Options | Text Editor | General | Show selection matches`.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

> This was a feature in VS15 and VS13.

Actually it was not.

It is a feature of the [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) extension. That extension is now just an installer for separate single feature extensions. I think you'll be wanting [Match Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MatchMargin).

For [Visual Studio 2022 Match Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MatchMargin2022) is also available.

Comment: I'm curious. I remember this feature being available on VS 2015, but I don't remember installing and extension for it. Was the Productivity Power Tools extension bundled with Visual Studio on former versions?

Comment: @MGranja Some highlighting was included in the box, but not for find ((IRC definition/reference highlight was included, which would often appear similar).

Comment: Yeah, that would explain it then. And them removing it from vanilla VS confused some people, like me.

Comment: @MGranja Visual Studio code has this feature built-in, maybe that's what you were thinking of?

Comment: Also just as a heads up, the default color scheme for Match Margin picks a rather subtle color, when I first loaded it I thought it wasn't working, but it turns out that it picked a color I could barely see, and it drew a very small bar because the file was large. You can change the color by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Match Color. The color it chooses to show in the scroll bar is the *foreground* (text) color, not the *background color*.

Comment: Another thing, it matches text, it's not necessarily language aware. E.g., if you have 8 functions with a local variable or parameter named `name`, and you click on `name`, it will highlight every instance of `name` in the file even though it isn't the same variable. Probably best to use this as a quick examination tool for global variables and fields. It's funny because the default identifier highlight system (that doesn't draw to the scroll bar) *is* language aware and will only highlight variables that are in the proper scope.

Comment: @jrh No, I almost never use VS code. I think Richard's suggestion is more likely.

Answer (score 18):

Right now, the only way I know (without installing new extensions) is to select (double click) the word and hit ctrl-f (find). Scroll map should highlight all occurences (mine are orange)

Comment: This doesn't work, because if I have two variables with the same name but different scope, they're both selected when only one of them should be.

Comment: It does. Author asks about "selected word in scrollbar" not a variable.

Answer (score 15):

There's another extension which does exactly this, with options to customize colors and more. it called **Word Highlight With Margin**.

The extension created by [Trung Kien Phan](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=publisher%3A%22Trung%20Kien%20Phan%22&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance)

### Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]

### VS2017/VS2019/2022 Version

Download link from Visual Studio market place - [VS2017, VS2019, VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungKienPhan.WordHighlight-18439)

### Previous versions:

[VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungKienPhan.WordHighlight-18643)

[VS2010, VS2012, VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungKienPhan.WordHighlight)

Answer (score 2):

The setting is in "Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced" and is called "Highlight references to symbol under cursor":
[image]

This is using Visual Studio 2019, version 16.1.25.

Answer (score 0):

MultiWordHighlight can highlight different words with different color

https://github.com/jendelel/MultiWordHighlight

***update***

1. How to install

   Install via Visual Studio Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jendelel.MultiWordHighlight).
2. How to use

   Right click on any word under the caret and select Toggle highlight of current word in the MultiWordHighlight menu.