# Variable highlighting for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, highlighting

How do I make Visual Studio 2017 highlight selected variables in the scrollbar? Not what the Word Highlight with Margin extension does, which just highlights all instances of the marked word, but rather how Visual Studio Code does it where it highlights instances of the selected variable within the scope on the scrollbar. By selected, I mean simply single-clicking on the variable once. The Match Margin extension is close, but isn't limited to variables and it disregards scope.

Visual Studio already highlights the variables, but they are not marked on the scrollbar like in Visual Studio Code.

Anyone know?

EDIT: It's not a [Visual Studio 17 highlight occurrences of selected word in scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229545/visual-studio-17-highlight-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-scrollbar) because that is about highlighting all instances in a file, while I want instances highlighted within scope. Furthermore, I explicitly said that Match Margin, which is considered the solution to the other question, isn't a solution to mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 17 highlight occurrences of selected word in scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229545/visual-studio-17-highlight-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-scrollbar)